# Mockito in order verify with any matchers

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm having some issues testing a servlet filter. The purpose of this servlet filter is to populate some http headers on response after the filterChain has been executed.  So what I am trying to test is that setHeader calls on my mockHttpServletResponse don't happen until after mockFilterChain.doFilter is called.

I am  using mockito:mockito-core:1.8.5

So, here is a sample code snippet

```
@Test
public void filterHeaderInjectionHappensLast() throws Exception {
    javax.servlet.Filter myFilter = new HeaderInjectionFilter();

    mockRequest = mock(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.class);
    mockResponse = mock(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.class);
    mockFilterChain = mock(javax.servlet.FilterChain.class);

    myFilter.doFilter(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockFilterChain);

    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockFilterChain, mockResponse);
    inOrder.verify(mockFilterChain).doFilter(mockRequest,mockResponse);
    inOrder.verify(mockResponse).setHeader(any(String.class),any(String.class));    
}
```

That test will fail do to the verify of setHeader passing any string arguments. If I change that setHeader verification call to accept specific arguments that are used in the code the test will pass successfully.  Can you not use wildcard matchers when you are verifying order like this?

HeaderInjectionFilter dumbed down looks like this

```
public class HeaderInjectionFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response); //Always doFilter before we add header to response

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpServletResponse.setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader(PRAGMA, "no-cache");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried simulating this, but can't. Can you give a few more details (version of Mockito?) and perhaps a bit of code I can copy/paste to try out?

Comment: Side note: Consider [`anyString()`](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyString()).

Comment: Can you give some more details on what the Objects `mockFilterChain` `mockResponse` and their api method signatures are? Do you know that the mockito matcher `any(Interface.class)` does _not_ verify that an object is an instance of some Interface or class? (and neither do `anyString()`, `anyBoolean()`, `any(MyClass.class)` etc) These matchers accept _any_ argument, the class/interface reference is only needed to make the compiler happy.

Comment: @bowmore Updated with more code and mockito version

Comment: I tried simulating it again, this time with your code, and Mockito 1.8.5, yet it still works. Which makes sense to me, as your code does what you tested for.

Comment: I'll have to try again. Maybe I just didn't have enough coffee last Friday.

Comment: So it looks like this occurred for me because I called setHeader(string, string) twice for two separate headers. This seems odd to me that you have to worry about the call count when you are just trying to verify the order in which methods are called. In my servlet code adding the second setHeader(PRAGMA, "no-cache"); gave me the issue.  I suppose this isn't a bug since the verify api explicitly states "Verifies interaction happened once in order."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This test was failing using any(String.class) because in the Filter implementation provided, two subsequent calls to response.setHeader. inOrder.verify verifies that the interaction happens once in order. So technically the test could be altered to

```
@Test
public void filterHeaderInjectionHappensLast() throws Exception {
    javax.servlet.Filter myFilter = new HeaderInjectionFilter();

    mockRequest = mock(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.class);
    mockResponse = mock(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.class);
    mockFilterChain = mock(javax.servlet.FilterChain.class);

    myFilter.doFilter(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockFilterChain);

    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockFilterChain, mockResponse);
    inOrder.verify(mockFilterChain).doFilter(mockRequest,mockResponse);
    inOrder.verify(mockResponse, times(2)).setHeader(any(String.class),any(String.class));    
}
```

Or, the test should explicitely test the specific header was set which is the path I would go down since it is less obscure for someone reading the test.